# Why can't a user see one of these tables when permissions look the same in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with a client where a user cannot see that there is data in one table but they can in another. The issue comes from the fact that I cannot seem to find any difference.

Below I show some information abhb_ahs_custom is a table that cannot be viewed but abha_ahs_custom has no issues being viewed

```
    task=# \dt abhb_ahs_custom
            List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  | Owner
--------+-----------------+-------+-------
 public | abhb_ahs_custom | table | atoms
(1 row)

task=# \dt abha_ahs_custom
            List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  | Owner
--------+-----------------+-------+-------
 public | abha_ahs_custom | table | atoms
(1 row)
```

And then

```
task=# \z abhb_ahs_custom
                                      Access privileges
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |       Access privileges        | Column access privileges
--------+-----------------+-------+--------------------------------+--------------------------
 public | abhb_ahs_custom | table | noble_restricted=arwdDxt/atoms+|
        |                 |       | atoms=arwdDxt/atoms            |
(1 row)

task=# \z abha_ahs_custom
                                      Access privileges
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |       Access privileges        | Column access privileges
--------+-----------------+-------+--------------------------------+--------------------------
 public | abha_ahs_custom | table | atoms=arwdDxt/atoms           +|
        |                 |       | noble_restricted=arwdDxt/atoms |
```

Is there something else I should be looking at here to find a difference that might point me to find out why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I still am not sure what the difference is and why it wasn't happening. However, I have fixed the problem. I ran a pg_dump on the table and then ran the file that was generated from the pg_dump. It appears my employer has modified pg_dump to include permissions we use. When I did this I was able to see the table with the correct user.